# Adobe Flex 4 rendering issues with text in disabled TextInput component

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I have an application which displays employee information. If the user opening the detailed employee information page is not authorized to make changes I set the TextInput to disabled.

Some users are reporting rendering issues with this. The TextInput's text value does not appear inside the box but is misaligned and is outside of the component. You can see the screenshow below of the disabled ID column where the numbers which are supposed to be in the TextInput box are far off to the right.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srqpn.jpg)

EDIT:

I am using Flex SDK 4.1.0.16076. Enabled property and text are controlled through a Swiz presentation model that gets injected into the MXML. I don't really have any issues with the setup except for this visual gitch.

I am not able to reproduce this on IE9 with Windows 7 using the latest Flash player but I can get the issue every time using IE6 with Windows XP. The text will correctly appear in the box if I reenable the TextInput but when I disable it again (via a checkbox through the interface controlling the enable property) it will misalign.

I also see the issue for the Spark List component, but it does not happen for mx:DateField or s:ComboBox which I also use.

Here is the code:

```
<mx:GridRow height="24">
            <mx:GridItem verticalAlign="middle">
                <s:Label text="ID:" fontWeight="bold"/>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem verticalAlign="middle">
                <s:TextInput id="IDTI" width="150" enabled="{model.IDTIEnabled}" text="{model.Id}" change="{model.Id = IDTI.text}" errorString="{model.IdError}"/>
            </mx:GridItem>
</mx:GridRow>
```

Comment: What version of Flex and `TextInput` do you using? Flex 3 or Flex 4? Spark or MX?

Comment: In addition to @constantiner requests; also show some code.  I've never seen a rendering situation like you describe and wonder if something else may be going on.

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I'm new to Stack Overflow and did not know I would not be notified about new comments.

Comment: @fyleow You should be able to find comments on your "Activity" page.  Press the 'down arrow" in the header next to your name.

Comment: @fyleow This is weird behavior for sure; can you provide a runnable sample that will create a reproducible case?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Thanks for the tip about comments. I see it now. I'll see what I can do about the sample, but I have to respect my employer's policy about these things.

Some developers have gotten around the issue by setting the editable property to false instead of disabling the component outright. I can work with that but I want a better visual indicator to the user that it's no longer editable (greyed out maybe?) Can you provide some guidance in that direction as a possible workaround? Thanks.

Comment: @fyleow you could copy the "disabled" styles to the enabled styles.  It's tedious though.  What you want to do should work without repositioning the text in weird places.